# Cartoon version of The Snow Queen

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animation

I remember watching one cartoon that is a retelling of the fairy tale by HC Andersen called "The Snow Queen". IIRC, it has a scene where Kai gets shards from the mirror in his eye and heart. I don't know if that version had the devil as the character who created the mirror or if, like the 1957 version, they had the Snow Queen as the mirror's owner in that version as well. Now, I remember only two scenes of note from that version. In one, after Kai gets the shard in his eye, there is a scene from his perspective. I believe, before that scene, he and Gerda are watering some flowers, and in this scene, his vision turns red and he sees one of their roses as being infested with worms, and so tramples on the rose, which upsets Gerda. In the other scene, Kai is abducted by the Snow Queen while sledding. He tried to detach his sled from the Snow Queen's carriage, but remarks that his efforts are futile since it's completely frozen to the carriage. Any idea as to what cartoon version of the Snow Queen this could be? This is definitely not the 1957 USSR version.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheSnowQueen

Comment: Wasn't this version playing on Netflix just a couple of months ago?

Comment: That sounds like it might be the one at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6hmAWzUs4g&list=TLPQMDQwOTIwMjGhP10H-dmWeA&index=1, which some people are claiming is a 1979 anime version.

Comment: Alas, I was being stupid and considered the 3D-animated _Snow Queen 3: Fire and Ice_ movie (which I couldn't make my way through, so... that, then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The version with a boy named Kai is a two part animation included on a DVD called *Hans Christian Anderson's Classics* along with a cartoon called *The Nightingale*.

I own a copy and can answer any questions that you have.

It's a Scandinavian film board/Irish film board co production.

[image: boy trampling on book, surrounded by roses]

[image: End credits: With the support of the MEDIA programmer of the European Commission, The Nordic Film & TV board; produced with the support and incentives of the Government of Ireland, Irish Film Board]

[image: End credits: Copyright 2002]

[image: End credits: Egmont Imagination, A Film, Magma Films]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you link to any sources that give production/distribution information about this?

Comment: I've added the information on the credits. I've taken my DVDs out of their cases so they take up less space. I've got the movie but the jacket is packed away somewhere.

Comment: Based on the drawing style, I would say this is a likely candidate. Does this have the scene with the flowers and where the viewer sees it from Kai's POV? If so, could you post a picture of that scene? Update: Now that the Youtube version has been posted, I would say that this is probably it. I'll watch the whole video to confirm whether this is the version I'm looking for.

Comment: I looked this one up myself earlier. It does have the scene where Kai stated that his sled is frozen to the carriage (I've added a video link to the answer). However, it doesn't have the POV shot of the worm/s in the rose, and Kai doesn't stamp on a rose, only on a book (although he does swat some roses with his hands). That scene occurs at around the 8 minute mark.

Comment: The style and the scene with the sled matches. I guess I was conflating the scene at 2:30 with the woman and the merchant with the scene where Kai comments that the roses look worm-eaten and tramples on the book.

Answer (score 5):

If it is the same one as [seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6hmAWzUs4g&list=TLPQMDQwOTIwMjGhP10H-dmWeA&index=1), this is *[The Snow Queen](http://www.copyrightencyclopedia.com/hans-christian-andersens-the-emperors-new-clothes-child/#id10949596)* a 1981 adaptation of a Japanese anime (still trying to pin down which one) by BFA Educational Media. When Gerda presents the rose, he states that there's a worm in it before dashing it from her hand, stomping on it, and then beginning to slash at the roses. Then, it shows his POV with her as a hideous creature defending the roses. He is shown later with his sled attached to the back of the Snow Queen's sleigh, albeit not with the dialog you mentioned. It's possible you saw a differently dubbed version of the scene from the anime.

[image: Kai attacking the flowers] [image: Kai's POV] [image: Kai trapped on his sled]

Comment: I feel a bit bad posting this without any information on the actual anime, but this is the best I've been able to do before having to leave for a shopping expedition.